# Qual é função das tags <embed> e <object> em HTML5?

Tags: html

Na explicação no site https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_object.asp explica como usar essas tags mais ambas fazem as mesmas coisas, então porque usar uma ou outra elas tem algo de diferente? ou uma é melhor que a outra em termos de processamento ? qual seria a melhor opção para ser usada ?

Comment: A pergunta é boa, mas temo que não consiga boas respostas. Procurei pela internet e só tem respostas ruins. Precisaria alguém com autoridade pra responder isto, não pode ser só opinião.

Answer (score 2):

Segundo a MDN

> *O elemento HTML `<object>` representa um recurso externo, que pode ser tratado como uma imagem, um contexto de navegação aninhado ou um recurso a ser manipulado por um plug-in.*

> *O Elemento HTML `<embed>` representa um ponto de integração para uma aplicação externa ou conteúdo interativo (em outras palavras, um plug-in).*

A diferença mais visível é que `<embed>` é um *empty element*, ou seja, não pode conter nenhum elemento dentro dele. Já o `<object>` permite, pode ser um *fallback*, que é um algo que será mostrado caso não haja suporte para aquele recurso externo, por exemplo, um SVG:

```
<object data="your.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
  <img src="yourfallback.jpg" />
</object>
```

Os elementos `<object>` também permite passar parâmetros para o recurso externo:

```
<object data="movie.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
  <param name="foo" value="bar">
</object>
```

O atributos permitidos no`<embed>` são:

- width
- height
- src
- type

Já os atributos permitidos no`<object>` são:

- width
- height
- data
- type
- form
- name
- usemap

Há outros mas estão obsoletos no HTML5

- [Elemento `<emped>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed)
- [Elemento `<object>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object)
- [Elemento `<param>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/param)

Answer (score -1):

*Embed*, se não me engano, é quando você vai colocar uma resolução de outro site ou servidor, geralmente coloca isso em um site para reproduzir o vídeo ou conteúdo *stream* de outro site.

*Object*, se eu não estiver enganado também, é quando você vai colocar um código responsável por criar um objeto como uma tabela, uma *source* em *flash* (este é o que eu tenho menos certeza).